# How to get fully background using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make the background cover? In this case, I'm using Bootstrap 4. You can see my CSS for the background image below:

```
<div id="form_wrapper" style="background-image:url('img/bg.png');margin: 0; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-size: 100% auto;">
```

[image: Resultant output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with enough code to show the problem, so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Comment: simply use `background-size: cover; width: 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: woah its work,adding height without edit background-size,thx u